# Migrating to new hosted zone causes DNS confusion (Route53)

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

Within the same AWS account i have an old hosted zone that I want to clean up by creating a new one with the same name but only add the relevant entrys and start version these entries using CloudFormation.

I've made so and updated the domain registrars with the four new NS records. So far so good.

The problem comes when I start to remov the old depricated entries from the old "disconnected" hosted zone. Doing so causes DNS error from resources in my AWS account, and partly from other parts of Internet. Accessing the dns entries from my coorporate network goes fine.

I'm only dealing with public hosted zones and the problems have been around for 48h and more.

Comment: Can you refer to the actual zone to review it from here?

Comment: Looks like I need to contact the registrar needs to check the delegation. I found: http://simpledns.com/lookup-dg.aspx and searching for my domain (cs.scania.com) returns the NS records for the old hosted zone. One of the old ns servers is for example: ns-218.awsdns-27.com

Comment: Great! Made so and it turned ot that there was an "external delegation setting" that was off. Now the correct ns records seams to be populated all over Internet! Thanks!